# How to change developer information in TestFlight

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I am using Xcode 8 , uploaded the app to the iTuneConnect and made the app available  for beta testing via TestFlight. But in Test flight iOS app , information for the **Developer** is wrong. I am unable to change the name of the developer. It would be helpful if anybody could help me to find the place from where test flight picking the developer's information. Or guide me to change the developer's Name

[Please refer the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ie3iQ.png)

Comment: Please help to resolve

Comment: Solved it!!!. We need to contact apple support to update company name or developer name :)